# Printing size of image - Error: Ambiguous use of 'size'

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickercontrollerOriginalImage"] {
        print(originalImage.size)
    }

}
```

`xCode` gives me the error

> "Ambiguous use of 'size'"

Anything that would help?

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

1. `originalImage` is `AnyObject`, not `UIImage`.
2. You have the wrong signature for `didFinishPickingMediaInfo`.

Your fixed code would be:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickercontrollerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
        print(originalImage.size)
    }
}
```

Comment: not necessarily **[String : Any]** as **[String : AnyObject]** will work also

Comment: @Sh_Khan The documentation states that the correct type is `[String: Any]`, not `[String: AnyObject]`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that code in swift 5.0 --->
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

```
    if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        print(originalImage.size)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need

```
if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickercontrollerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {--}
```

as `info` is `[String : AnyObject]`  , so you need to cast `AnyObject` to `UIImage`